# Is Android studio faster on a Linux pc?

Tags: android, linux, performance, android-studio

I have been using android studio from the moment it came out,It has been considerably slow while building when doing large projects..

I have been running it on a windows PC [windows 7 Home Basic] with 4 gb ram and core i5 processor

I have been thinking of migrating to a Linux OS lately [Elementary OS in mind]

And i just really want to know whether *Android studio is faster on a Linux machine or a windows machine*

Comment: I doubt that there is much direct speed difference between the two. I find that Windows tends to use more system RAM, and so if you are short on RAM, Linux may help improve speed, due to less paging of RAM to disk and back.

Comment: it's not a game so I don't know why speed is something important here....

Comment: Your hardware is more important that the OS. Especially a hard disk slows down your system, comparing to an SSD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible you would have faster performance on a Linux OS, but that would most likely be due to less processes operating simultaneously on your OS.  If you have File indexing turned on under Windows, or antivirus software, they could degrade your overall build speed.  Perhaps try optimizing your current configuration before migrating to a new OS that could introduce a host of new issues.

Comment: …and also your keyboard shortcuts are going to be a pain. A little bit less between Windows and Linux, but from OS X to Linux, the cmd vs. Control will drive you nuts (or force you to use a different keymap)